# Array parameter in arm template is being evaluated as empty array?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template with array parameter and I am passing parameters like this:

azuredeploy.json

```
"allowedLocations": {
  "type": "array",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "localtions"
  },
},
```

azuredeployparameters.json

```
"allowedLocations": {
    "value": [
      "eastus2"
    ]
},
```

I am using Azure devops pipeline to deploy this. Once deployment happens, in the azure portal allowedLocations comes as:

```
[[]]
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Hi @nikhita kataria, I try this code and it works, "allowedLocations": {
                "type": "array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    "eastus2"
                ],
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "localtions"
                }
            }
 , could you please check the pipeline log and notice the parameter value?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?